# How to change the binary path for a build project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, detox

When using Detox, I need to set `binaryPath` for `.app`.

Currently I have this:

```
ios/build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Project.app
```

I need it to be like this:

```
ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Project.app
```

I suspect that the problem is in the Build Settings of my XCode.

Can you tell me how I can change the directory?

Comment: I answered you but it was pretty easy to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Build Settings` of your project, search for "`Build Products Path`"

By default it's "`build`", but you can change it.

[image: Xcode build project path]

Comment: Unfortunately, when building the project, it does not change my directory

Comment: Did you cleaned your project before building it ?

Comment: No, but how can I do it?